# Android: Color preference?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I would like to add an option to my application preferences that allows users to select a color, but am not sure of a good strategy.  I have a color picker which I can show in a dialog, so I could use a dialog preference.  But I see no good way of indicating in the dialog preference what the current color is (I would like to be able to add a "swatch" of color to the preference layout, to indicate the current color; or something similar).  Any suggestions for how to make a user friendly color preference?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this one: [mColorPicker](https://github.com/danielnilsson9/color-picker-view)

It is very easy to use. You can download the code and see an example.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps you out:

http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Comment: thanks, but not particularly.  I would like a user friendly Preference entry, for color.  One that in some way indicates the current color.

Answer (score 0):

I need the same preference interface, and it looks like displaying the color swatch should be possible by overriding [getLayoutResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getLayoutResource%28%29) in the base Preference class and implementing an xml layout to include the swatch.